# Bug in Rebuild on SQL Server 2016 and above?

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-internals

### Question Summary

A fragmented Clustered Index is not performing well, even after a `REBUILD` of the index. If the index is `REORGANIZED` then performance increases for the given table/index.

I am seeing this unusual behavior only on SQL Server 2016 and above, I have tested this scenario on different hardware and different versions (all personal machines and all have the conventional rotating hard disk). Let me know if need any more information.

Is this a bug in SQL Server 2016 and onwards?

---

I can provide the complete details and analysis with the script if anybody wants, but not providing right now because the script quite large and will take a lot of space in the question.

Please test the shorter version of sample script taken from the provided link below in your DEV environment if you have SQL Server 2016 and above.

#### SCRIPT

```
-- SECTION 1
/*
Create a Test Folder in the machine and spefiy the drive in which you created
*/
USE MASTER

CREATE DATABASE RebuildTest
ON 
( NAME = 'RebuildTest',
    FILENAME = 'F:\TEST\RebuildTest_db.mdf',
    SIZE = 200MB,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
    FILEGROWTH = 50MB )
LOG ON
( NAME = 'RebuildTest_log',
    FILENAME = 'F:\TEST\RebuildTest_db.ldf',
    SIZE = 100MB,
      MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB ) ;
GO

BEGIN TRAN

USE RebuildTest

select  top 1000000
row_number () over ( order by (Select null)) n into Numbers from
sys.all_columns  a cross  join  sys.all_columns

CREATE TABLE [DBO].FRAG3 (
Primarykey int NOT NULL ,
SomeData3 char(1000) NOT NULL )

ALTER TABLE DBO.FRAG3
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FRAG3 PRIMARY KEY (Primarykey)

INSERT INTO [DBO].FRAG3
SELECT n , 'Some text..'
FROM Numbers
Where N/2 = N/2.0

Update DBO.FRAG3 SET Primarykey =  Primarykey-500001
Where  Primarykey>500001

COMMIT

 -- SECTION 2

SELECT @@VERSION

/*                                                       BEGIN PART FRAG1.1     */

----- BEGIN CLEANBUFFER AND DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
Select Count_Big (*) From [DBO].[FRAG3] Where Primarykey >0 Option (MAxDop 1)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

----- END CLEANBUFFER AND DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME

-------------BEGIN PART FRAG1.2: REBUILD THE INDEX AND TEST AGAIN

--BEGIN Rebuild the Index
Alter Table [DBO].[FRAG3] REBUILD
--END  Rebuild the Index

----- BEGIN CLEANBUFFER FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
Select Count_Big (*) From [DBO].[FRAG3] Where Primarykey >0 Option (MAxDop 1)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
----- END CLEANBUFFER  FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME

--BEGIN REORGANIZE the Index
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [DBO].[FRAG3] REORGANIZE ;
--END REORGANIZE the Index

----- BEGIN CLEANBUFFER  FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
Select Count_Big (*) From [DBO].[FRAG3] Where Primarykey >0 Option (MAxDop 1)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
----- END CLEANBUFFER  FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME

-------------BEGIN PART FRAG1.4: REBUILD THE INDEX AND TEST AGAIN

--BEGIN Rebuild the Index
Alter Table [DBO].[FRAG3] REBUILD
--END  Rebuild the Index

----- BEGIN CLEANBUFFER FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
Select Count_Big (*) From [DBO].[FRAG3] Where Primarykey >0 Option (MAxDop 1)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
----- END CLEANBUFFER  FROM DATABASE AND MEASURE TIME

-------------END PART FRAG1.4: REBUILD THE INDEX AND TEST AGAIN
```

#### Results

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Crystal Disk Mark Test Results

[image]

[image]

#### Detail

I am seeing an unusual behavior of storage engine (maybe) on SQL Server 2016 and above, I have created a highly fragmented table for (read problems with fragmentation) demo purpose then rebuilt it.

Even after rebuilding the index performance doesn't increase as expected.
To make sure data access pattern should be in key order not in IAM-driven (Allocation Order Scan), I used the range predicate.

Initially, I thought maybe SQL Server 2016 and above is more aggressive for large scans. To check that, I adjusted the  page count and row count but the performance pattern doesn't change. I tested all on a personal system so I can say there was no other user activity was going on.

I have tested this behavior on other hardware as well (**all have traditional rotating hard disks**). Performance patterns are almost same.

I have checked wait stats all seem normal only `PAGELATCH_IO` (using Paul Randal script) there. I checked data pages using DMV `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations` it also seems ok.

If I reorganize the table or move all the data to a new table with same index definition disk IO performance increases. I have checked this with 
perfmon and it seems like reorganizing index /new table  can leverage sequential IO and the rebuild index still using the random reads in spite of the fact that  both have almost same data pages internal and external fragmentation.

I am attaching the complete query with the results on my system I captured.
if you guys have SQL Server 2016 and above DEV box, please check this and share your results.

**WARNING**: This test consists some undocumented commands and `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` so not at all run at the production server.

If this is really a bug I think I should file it.

So the question is: Is it really a bug or I am missing something ;)

#### Links (pastebin)

[1 Fragmented Table Creation](https://pastebin.com/UFavBrnv)

[2 Supporting SPs RUN AFTER TABLE CREATION](https://pastebin.com/JrFNGajm)

[3 Test](https://pastebin.com/uihLPDbF)

[4 Any Problem With Rebuild](https://pastebin.com/JtPHtsEL)

[5 Put Data in New Table](https://pastebin.com/wxsRn1FV)

#### Links:(Google Drive)

[6 Download Result ON My SYSTEMS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9rldoCTYm_VamlfUzRwcW1EUUE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63055/discussion-on-question-by-neeraj-prasad-sharma-bug-in-rebuild-on-sql-server-2016)**. Please use that facility for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The queries in question exercise the [SQL Server read-ahead](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx) feature. With read-ahead performance optimization, the SQL Server storage engine prefetches data during scans so that pages are already in buffer cache when needed by the query so less time is spent waiting for data during query execution.

The difference in execution times with read-alead reflects how well (or not) the storage system and Windows APIs handle large IO sizes along with differences in SQL Server read ahead behavior that vary by version. Older SQL Server versions (SQL Server 2008 R2 in the aforementioned article) limit prefeatch to 512K IO sizes whereas SQL Server 2016 and later issue read ahead IO in larger sizes to leverage capabilities of modern production grade commodity hardware (RAID and SSD). Keep in mind that SQL Server is generally optimized to run on current generation hardware at the time of release, exploiting larger processor cache, NUMA architecture, and storage system IOPS/bandwidth capability. Furthermore, Enterprise/Developer editions also perform prefetch more aggressively than lesser editions to maximize throughput even more.

To better understand the reason for the different performance of SQL 2008 R2 compared to later versions, I executed a modified versions of your scripts on a older physical machine with different versions of SQL Server Developer Edition. This test box has both 7200 RPM HDD and SATA SSD, allowing the same test to be run on the same machine against different storage systems and SQL versions. I captured file_read and file_read_completed events during each test with an Extended Event trace for more detailed analysis of IO and timings.

**The results show roughly comparable performance with all SQL Server versions and storage system types except for SQL Server 2012 and later versions on a single HDD spindle following the clustered index rebuild.** Interestingly, the XE trace showed "Contiguous" mode during read-ahead scans in SQL Server 2008 R2 only; the trace showed "Scatter/Gather" mode was used in all other versions. I can't say if this difference contributes to the faster performance.

Also, analysis of the trace data shows SQL 2016 issues much larger reads during read ahead scans and the average IO size varies by storage type. This doesn't necessarily mean SQL Server adjusts the read-ahead IO size based on physical hardware but instead that it might adjust the size based on unknown measurements. The heuristics used by the storage engine are not documented and may vary by version and patch level.

Below is a summary of test timings. I'll add more information gathered from the traces when I have some more time (unfortunately IO size is not available in SQL Server 2008 R2 XE).  In summary, the IO profile differs by version and storage type. The average IO size for versions through SQL Server 2014 never exceeded 512K whereas SQL Server 2016 read over 4MB in a single IO in these tests. The number of outstanding reads was also much less in the SQL 2016 test because SQL Server fewer IO requests to accomplish the same work.

```
SQL_Version Storage Device         Test                   Duration
SQL 2008 R2    HDD             initial table            00:00:03.686
SQL 2012       HDD             initial table            00:00:03.725
SQL 2014       HDD             initial table            00:00:03.706
SQL 2016       HDD             initial table            00:00:03.654
SQL 2008 R2    HDD             fragmented table         00:00:07.796
SQL 2012       HDD             fragmented table         00:00:08.026
SQL 2014       HDD             fragmented table         00:00:07.837
SQL 2016       HDD             fragmented table         00:00:06.097
SQL 2008 R2    HDD             after rebuild            00:00:06.962
SQL 2012       HDD             after rebuild            00:00:21.129
SQL 2014       HDD             after rebuild            00:00:19.501
SQL 2016       HDD             after rebuild            00:00:21.377
SQL 2008 R2    HDD             after reorg              00:00:04.103
SQL 2012       HDD             after reorg              00:00:03.974
SQL 2014       HDD             after reorg              00:00:04.076
SQL 2016       HDD             after reorg              00:00:03.610
SQL 2008 R2    HDD             after reorg and rebuild  00:00:07.201
SQL 2012       HDD             after reorg and rebuild  00:00:21.839
SQL 2014       HDD             after reorg and rebuild  00:00:20.199
SQL 2016       HDD             after reorg and rebuild  00:00:21.782
SQL 2008 R2    SATA SSD        initial table            00:00:02.083
SQL 2012       SATA SSD        initial table            00:00:02.071
SQL 2014       SATA SSD        initial table            00:00:02.074
SQL 2016       SATA SSD        initial table            00:00:02.066
SQL 2008 R2    SATA SSD        fragmented table         00:00:03.134
SQL 2012       SATA SSD        fragmented table         00:00:03.129
SQL 2014       SATA SSD        fragmented table         00:00:03.129
SQL 2016       SATA SSD        fragmented table         00:00:03.113
SQL 2008 R2    SATA SSD        after rebuild            00:00:02.065
SQL 2012       SATA SSD        after rebuild            00:00:02.097
SQL 2014       SATA SSD        after rebuild            00:00:02.071
SQL 2016       SATA SSD        after rebuild            00:00:02.078
SQL 2008 R2    SATA SSD        after reorg              00:00:02.064
SQL 2012       SATA SSD        after reorg              00:00:02.082
SQL 2014       SATA SSD        after reorg              00:00:02.067
SQL 2016       SATA SSD        after reorg              00:00:02.072
SQL 2008 R2    SATA SSD        after reorg and rebuild  00:00:02.078
SQL 2012       SATA SSD        after reorg and rebuild  00:00:02.087
SQL 2014       SATA SSD        after reorg and rebuild  00:00:02.087
SQL 2016       SATA SSD        after reorg and rebuild  00:00:02.079
```

I also ran these tests on a VM with a HDD-backed SAN and observed similar performance as the SATA SSD. So the bottom line is this performance issue occurs only with a single-spindle HDD data file, something that is common only on PCs, not modern production systems. Whether or not this should be considered a performance regression bug is questionable but I'll reach out to see if I can get more information.

**EDIT**

I reached out to my contacts and Erland Sommarskog pointed out the higher fragment count reported by sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats in later versions. Digging deeper, I noticed the REBUILD statement is a parallel query. The implication is that **a parallel rebuild may actually increase the fragment count (and even introduce fragmentation on a table with no fragmentation) because space allocations are done in parallel.** This will generally not affect performance except with read-ahead scans and is particularly a problem with singe-spindle spinning media as the tests show. This is a consideration in all SQL versions.

Paul Randal pointed this out as by design and referenced [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/03/02/how-it-works-max-dop-level-and-parallel-index-builds/) for more information. A best practice for index rebuilds for a workload that will leverage read-ahead scans (e.g. data warehousing) is to rebuild `WITH (MAXDOP = 1)`;